# Sort by time PHP

Tags: php

i have this function `sort_by_time`, the purpose of this function is to swap the `time1` if the `time2` is greater than `time1` but my problem is im having an error of **Undefined offset: 0**. Sometimes the error is **Undefined offset: 1**. or **Undefined offset: 2**. Can someone help me to prevent this error in my code? I'm thinking this in these last 3 days but i can't think of any solution on this.

in this line the error occur.

```
      if (Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes($_time[$j]->time_in) > Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes($_time[$j+1]->time_in))
```

This error occurs because the `$_time[0]` is not set.

Sample time. This is dynamic not only limited to `3` sometimes it's `4`, sometimes it's `5` or `1`.

- 1 => {#6356}
- 2 => {#6352}
- 3 => {#6257}

  Here's my full function code

  ```
  public static function sort_by_time($_time)
  {
      $count = 0;


      $n = count($_time);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $n-1; $i++)
      {
          for ($j = 0; $j < $n-$i-1; $j++)
          {
              if (Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes($_time[$j]->time_in) > Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes($_time[$j+1]->time_in))
              {

                  // swap temp and arr[i]
                  $temp = $_time[$j];
                  $_time[$j] = $_time[$j+1];
                  $_time[$j+1] = $temp;

              }
          }
      }


      return $_time;
  }
  ```

Comment: Quote the full, exact, error details.

Comment: @AndyG the full error says ‘Undefined offset: 0”’

Comment: @nethkennnnn which line ? which var ?

Comment: @nethkennnnn try `$_time = array_values($_time);` at beginning of function

Comment: ‘$_time[$j]->time_in’ @Fky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static function sort_by_time($_time)
{
    usort($_time,function($ad,$bd)
    {
        $ad = Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes($ad->time_in);
        $bd = Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes($bd->time_in);

        if ($ad == $bd) {
           return 0;
        }

        return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return $_time;
}
```

if it doesn't work the problem can be in function `Payroll2::convert_time_in_minutes`